# Group Custom post type in a taxonomy page by its child taxomony

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

I hope you can help me, guys. I've create custom post type and custom taxonomy with Custom Post Type UI plugin. Then i create an page taxonomy-mycustomtaxonomy.php.

When i access, for example, a url http://mysiteurl/mycustomtaxonomy/maintaxonomy1/ i have to show:

```
maintaxonomy1-title
maintaxonomy1-description

--

childtaxonomy1-title
childtaxonomy1-description
post1
post2
post3
...

--

childtaxonomy2-title
childtaxonomy2-description
post1
post2
...

--

...
```

I don't want to show all posts of maintaxonomy1. Only the child posts of that.

I start with this:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("mycustomtaxonomy");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
            'post_per_page' => 100,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'mycustomtaxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id
                )
            )
        ));
        // the loop
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            // do loop content
            echo '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
        endwhile;
        // reset $post so that the rest of the template is in the original context
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}?>
```

But it show posts of maintaxonomy1. Besides, show posts too of all taxonomies and i have to show only the posts of taxonomy that is in url address.

I hope you understand my question and would really apreaciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Seems a little confused at first, but the logic is here:

```
<?php $term = get_queried_object(); ?>

<?php echo $term->name; ?>

<?php 
$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
if($children) { 

foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    ?>

    <?php echo '<li>' . $child->name . '</li>'; ?>

    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'mycustomtaxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $child->term_taxonomy_id
                )
            )
        ));
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>

        <?php echo '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>'; ?>

        <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php }
} ?>
```

Hope it help others!

Comment: Please accept your own answer ;-)